# How can I improve this code?

Tags: graphics3d, random, code-review, version-7, random-process

The code below is working well, but it's very slow in the Manipulate box.  I know that the `Do` and `AppendTo` parts aren't very efficient.  Is there a better way in doing the same calculation?  Take note that the order of the three `Do/AppendTo` is important, since the result isn't the same if the order is changed.  I also need to know if these `Do` operations are well declared in that code, since Mathematica doesn't format the code in a nice way, while it doesn't give any error message.  Please, take note that I'm using a very old version of Mathematica (7.0), so any suggestion should be compatible with old versions of Mma.

```
(* pts is initially an uniform distribution of "p" points in space, that I call "clusters". *)
(* Then I add randomly "q" points (galaxies) to that distribution of clusters. *)
(* The second and third Do add 5000 + 8000 more galaxies, to get irregular clusters of thousands of galaxies (the dots in the simulation). *)

 galaxies[p_, q_, r_] := Module[
    {pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {p, 3}]},
    Do[AppendTo[pts, RandomChoice[pts] + 1.00 r RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]],
        {i, q}];pts
    Do[AppendTo[pts, RandomChoice[pts] + 0.33 r RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]],
        {i, 5000}];pts
    Do[AppendTo[pts, RandomChoice[pts] + 0.11 r RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]],
        {i, 8000}];pts
 ]

 view[p_, q_, r_] := Show[
    Graphics3D[{RGBColor[{0.5, 0.4, 1.0, 0.4}], PointSize[0.003], Point[galaxies[p, q, r]]}],
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    Boxed -> True,
    Background -> Black,
    ImageSize -> {700, 700},
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}
 ]

 Manipulate[
    view[p, q, r],
    {{p, 500, "p"}, 1, 1000, 1},
    {{q, 10000, "q"}, 0, 10000, 1},
    {{r, 0.05, "scale"}, 0.01, 0.2, 0.001}
 ]
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

Comment: Please add comments to your `galaxy` code that explain what each line does. It would then be a lot easier for people to think of a new implementation, rather than trying to figure out what you did and fix it from there. Having to understand what you want from suboptimal code is a big barrier.

Comment: Your code on Mathematica version 13.0.1.0 running on an Apple MacBook Pro M1 runs effortlessly, even with all three `Manipulate` controls in animation mode.  Maybe it's time to upgrade Mathematica and/or your machine.

Comment: @Jagra, yes, I agree.  My version of Mma is very old (7.0), and can't change it until I upgrade the whole computer (maybe in october).  So you say that the Manipulate box runs smooth on your setup?  Please, can you post an animated gif?

Comment: No time to create and post a gif.  That said, your code might run in the [Wolfram Cloud[(https://www.wolframcloud.com).  I think the processing would run on Wolfram's servers, you'd just see results in a browser (if memory serves).  Basic Plan = free.

Comment: The main improvements I can think of are to pre-allocate the `pts` list, remove `AppendTo`, make the random seed a parameter and use memoization (possibly on disk), so the display doesn't have to calculate multiple times the same.

Comment: Just tried it on Wolfram Cloud.  It doesn't do animation but it does seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
addPoints[pts_, num_, scale_] := 
  Join @@ {pts, 
    RandomChoice[pts, num] + RandomReal[{-scale, scale}, {num, 3}]};


 galaxiesNew[p_, q_, r_] := Module[
  {pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {p, 3}]},
  pts = Nest[addPoints[#, 1, r] &, pts, q];
  pts = Nest[addPoints[#, 1, 0.33*r] &, pts, 5000];
  pts = Nest[addPoints[#, 1, 0.11*r] &, pts, 8000];
  pts
  ]
```

Getting rid of the `Do` loops and `AppendTo` speeds up galaxy generation by about 30%.

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[galaxies[500, 10000, 0.05]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[galaxiesNew[500, 10000, 0.05]]
```

Gives me 0.47s v. 0.35s.

Edit: I missed the fact that the `Do` loop was updating `pts` before every call to `RandomChoice` meaning each subsequent call should have access to previously generated points. I accommodated this using `Nest` and only adding one point at a time, the increased number of calls to `Join` and `RandomReal`, and `RandomChoice` mean the speedup isn't so great.

Comment: Apologies, I must have missed something. I'll take a look.

Comment: Should provide the same functionality now, but the speed up isn't as great.

Comment: Why the num variable in your definition of addPoints?  Why it is set to 1 everywhere else?

Comment: When I first wrote it I thought you could generate all your random points at once, so I kept `num` general so I could apply it three times for each of your scales. It was an easier edit to the post to just use the same function with `num=1` than to redefine the function. You could reduce the number of parameters in `addPoints` and set it to one there if you wanted.

Comment: Using **RandomChoice[pts]** instead of **RandomChoice[pts, 1]** gives troubles ($Abort).  Why?  Using **RandomChoice[pts, 1]** solves the issue.  I don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: That's because `RandomChoice[pts]` returns `{x,y,z}`, whereas `RandomChoice[pts,1]` returns `{{x,y,z}}`, which matches dimensions with `RandomReal[{-1,1},{1,3}]`. If you want to use `RandomChoice[pts]` you need to use `Join@@{pts,{RandomChoice[pts]+RandomReal[{-scale,scale},3]}}`.

Comment: what is your setup?  And how smooth your version of the code is working, when you play with the Manipulate box?

Comment: It's about as smooth as I could expect with it taking a considerable fraction of a second just to generate the points that will be plotted. I've got a several years old macbook pro running macOS 12.4 and MMA 12.

Comment: N.J., in your EDIT, you said that your code is adding just 1 point at a time (I clearly see it).  Do you think it's possible to add several points at once (say 10, instead of 1), by *slightly* modifying the **Nest/Join/RandomChoice** part?

Comment: Absolutely, you just change the second parameter of `addPoints` to `10`. But be careful, this will change the behavior of the code as those ten points will all choose from the same set of points only the next batch of ten will have the last 10 integrated. You will also probably need to scale `q`, 5000, 8000, by 1/10 to get the same number of points.

Comment: Wow!  There are lots of possibilities here.  From the simple rules of uniform randomization, we could get very nice and natural looking distributions, fractal like,  This is fascinating!

Answer (score 4):

First, get rid of `AppendTo` and replace it with a preallocation of the array because you know the size in advance.

Second, use `RandomInteger` instead of `RandomSample`.

Finally, compile your code.

```
galaxiesFaster[p_, q_, r_] := Module[{t1 = 5000, t2 = 8000, pts},
   pts = ConstantArray[{0., 0., 0.}, p + q + t1 + t2];
   pts[[1 ;; p]] = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {p, 3}];
   Do[pts[[p + i]] = 
     pts[[RandomInteger[{1, p + i - 1}]]] + 
      1.00 r RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 3], {i, q}];
   Do[pts[[p + q + i]] = 
     pts[[RandomInteger[{1, p + q + i - 1}]]] + 
      0.33 r RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 3], {i, t1}];
   Do[pts[[p + q + t1 + i]] = 
     pts[[RandomInteger[{1, p + q + t1 + i - 1}]]] + 
      0.11 r RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 3], {i, t2}];
   pts];

galaxiesCompiled = Compile[{{p, _Integer}, {q, _Integer}, r},
   Module[{t1 = 5000, t2 = 8000, 
     pts = ConstantArray[{0., 0., 0.}, p + q + t1 + t2]},
    pts[[1 ;; p]] = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {p, 3}];
    Do[pts[[p + i]] = 
      pts[[RandomInteger[{1, p + i - 1}]]] + 
       1.00 r RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 3], {i, q}];
    Do[pts[[p + q + i]] = 
      pts[[RandomInteger[{1, p + q + i - 1}]]] + 
       0.33 r RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 3], {i, t1}];
    Do[pts[[p + q + t1 + i]] = 
      pts[[RandomInteger[{1, p + q + t1 + i - 1}]]] + 
       0.11 r RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 3], {i, t2}];
    pts], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

galaxies[500, 10000, 0.05] // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.8353 *)

galaxiesFaster[500, 10000, 0.05] // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.2402 *)

galaxiesCompiled[500, 10000, 0.05] // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.0309 *)
```

The first two fix-ups (`galaxiesFaster`) produce approximately 3.5 times faster executions, and then compiling the code (`galaxiesCompiled`) is furthermore 7.5 times faster.

In version 7, there is no `RuntimeOptions` option for `Compile`, so you have to remove this.

Comment: very nice solution.

Comment: How do I insert your code into mine (in my question above)?  I must admit that I don't understand your code at all!  :-(

Comment: @Cham, instead of using ``galaxies``, use ``galaxiesCompiled``. So for example: ``view[p_, q_, r_] := Show[ ..., Point[galaxiesCompiled[p, q, r]] ...]``.

Comment: Please, do not be so vague – it doesn't help anyone. What kind of error messages are you getting? Include a screenshot.

Comment: If you use v7, the problem might be in ``RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"``. Try removing this option. Unfortunately, I do not have v7 and cannot test it myself.

Comment: @Domen, Even if you remove the compilation this is still about 5x faster than the original just using a pre-allocated array. Considerably smoother in `Manipulate`.

Comment: `galaxiesUnCompiled[p_, q_, r_] := Module[
   {t1 = 5000, t2 = 8000, pts},
   pts = ConstantArray[{0., 0., 0.}, p + q + t1 + t2];
   pts[[1 ;; p]] = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {p, 3}];
   Do[pts[[p + i]] = 
     pts[[RandomInteger[{1, p + i - 1}]]] + 
      1.00 r RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 3], {i, q}];
   Do[pts[[p + q + i]] = 
     pts[[RandomInteger[{1, p + q + i - 1}]]] + 
      0.33 r RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 3], {i, t1}];
   Do[pts[[p + q + t1 + i]] = 
     pts[[RandomInteger[{1, p + q + t1 + i - 1}]]] + 
      0.11 r RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 3], {i, t2}];
   pts];`

Comment: In case you want to add it to your answer.

Comment: @N.J.Evans, thanks! I have added this to my answer.

Comment: **galaxiesFaster[p, q, r]** works very well.  I'll study this version.  Thanks!